# WPF C# How to check URI file exists

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the code like this.
When lan is null, I am getting exception **TypeInitializationException.**

**Is there any way to check null for URI??**

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();

dict.Source = new Uri("/Emdep.Geos.UI.Common;component/Resources/Language." + lan + ".xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emdep.Geos.UI.Common.dll## Heading ##
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but to my mind it's fine to get exception when you do the stuff you described. lan should not be null. It should be initialized with default language your app support. It will be weird to check whether you have language in your embedded resources or not.

Comment: I mean, lan is any filename/null value that not exists in computer then throws exception

Comment: What do you want to do if `lan` is `null`?

Comment: @SagarKhade So I understand you correctly it not only throws this exception when `lan` is `null` but also when the filepath doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to catch the `FileNotFoundException` that occurs when the `ResourceDictionary` could not be found:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
try
{
    dict.Source = new Uri("/Emdep.Geos.UI.Common;component/Resources/Language." + lan + ".xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    //the resource dictionary could not be located/loaded...
}
```

Comment: it's an IOException that's thrown rather than a FileNotFoundException

Comment: @kjhf: No, it's not.

Comment: ok dug some more, the exception I had was "Cannot locate resource '(uri)'" which I took to be file not found and was typed as IOException. However the real cause of the exception was because the assembly was not found rather than the file. Using your code as-is produces an IOException because my assembly doesn't know about `Emdep.Geos.UI.Common`