# How to check if a pack/component Uri exists in a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, uri, nuget-package, file-exists

How can I check if a `Uri` (file) exists in a referenced project?

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52762407/1563422) I've tried catching a `FileNotFound` exception but it isn't throwing any exceptions at all

```
string x;

try {
    var Uri = new Uri("/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/some_wrong_file.png",
        UriKind.Relative);
    x = "a";
}

catch(Exception) {
    x = "b";
}

MessageBox.Show(x);
```

Per [an MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d124e63-b92a-4c50-a9fe-387e86a3b816/how-to-check-if-file-exists-with-pack-paths?forum=wpf), I've tried checking if the resultant `Bitmap` is null, but it always shows 'a':

```
string x;

try {
    var Bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
        "/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/some_wrong_file.png", UriKind.Relative));
    Flag_Image.Source = Bitmap ?? throw new Exception();
    x = "a";
}

catch(Exception) {
    Flag_Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
        "/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/ca.png", UriKind.Relative));
    x = "b";
}

MessageBox.Show(x);
```

Comment: In code behind, you should write the full Pack URI, including its prefix. It's also not a relative URI: `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/some_wrong_file.png")`

Comment: @Clemens Nice, that worked - thanks! Something so simple..